# In Texas Hold'em, how does the floor penalize a player who has received more chips than he should have (as through an add-on)?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

I was running a poker tournament this evening. The type of tourney is freezeout with up to a $25 dollar add-on worth 5500 in chips. I seated him, gave him the starting stack plus the add-on, and told him that I needed the marker from him which signified he purchased the add-on. At a later point, he had the marker on the table, which is in play, and when he went all in, he was awarded an additional 5500 in chips, due to the in play marker. How would I penalize/fix this situation in the event that my attention is not drawn to the error immediately?

Comment: At what point did the player get a marker saying they were entitled to an add on?  Would this not be given to them at the registration desk with there starting chips?  Undoing a mistake like that is a tricky one as lots to considers, Did the player make an honest mistake or was it deliberate cheating?  How do you avoid other players feeling disgruntled?  Did they player accept they made a mistake or deny it?  Can the mistake be proven using casino security footage?

Comment: To the best of my ability to gauge the situation, there was no deliberate attempt to game or cheat the system or other players. It was a mistake made by everyone, including myself. The player was given his add-on chips at start with a verbal commitment. No marker was presented to me until much later.

Comment: my experience in poker is that 'verbal declarations are binding'.   I'm also confused as to how a player goes all in and then gains an add on?  I've never known any casino allow a player to buy extra chips during a hand.  Personally I would remove the 5500 from the player and make sure any player who lost extra 5500 during that hand also had that returned.   However I can't give you a specific rules guideline from Roberts Rules as an answer.  You might have more luck at poker.stackexchange.com